# Ubuntu boots into tty1 after driver downgrade

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, xorg

Earlier today I downgraded the driver for my nvidia 240 GT from version 310 to version 304 using ubuntus "additional drivers" utility. After the install I rebooted but instead of opening unity and allowing me to login it booted into tty1 instead. After using the "startx" command I got the message, "nvidia: API mismatch: the nvidia kernel module has version 310.14, but this nvidia driver component has version 304.43." What can I do to solve this?

Edit:
Solved my own problem by purging all nvidia packaged and reinstalling my drivers.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks,

Same thing happend to me. I did the same as above and it solved it.

For less experienced linux users these are the commands to run:

1. Purge nvidia related stuff:

   `sudo apt-get purge nvidia*`
2. Restart machine:

   `sudo shutdown -r now`

This will get you machine up and running with X again.
Now.. you need to pick a driver from the "Additional Drivers" utility built into the system and by that reinstall the drivers to your machine.